# docker-compose always exec using nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I am pulling my hair on this.. I don't know where it went wrong, but it seems that the docker container always execute whatever command I put with nodejs. The only way it result not with an error, is when I put "index.js" as single command at `docker-compose.yml`

[image]

I am new with docker, but is there some place I should look at?

My dockerfile:

```
FROM node:17
WORKDIR /opt/application
COPY ./certificate/server* ./certificate/
COPY package.json .
COPY config.json .
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY ./src/ ./src
RUN npm install nodemon typescript -g
RUN npm install
RUN tsc -p .
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "80:3000"
    container_name: nodejs
    volumes:
      - "./src:/opt/application/src"
    depends_on:
      - "mongo"
    command:
      - "tsc -w"
      - "nodemon"
  mongo:
    image: "mongo:latest"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

I don't know where the configuration to add nodejs is.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: That Compose setup is equivalent to running the single shell command `'tsc -w' nodemon`.  You seem to have pasted an image file instead of an error message, but you'll probably get some sort of "not found" error when there's no command `tsc\ -w` including the space in the command filename.  Do you want to remove the `volumes:` and `command:` override; `RUN tsc` (or `RUN npm build`) in the Dockerfile; and also set `CMD npm start` in the Dockerfile?

Comment: seems like you added commands in your compose under web container and you mentioned the container name as nodejs. therefore the commands are run in this nodejs container and when you see the error, it is suffixed by the container name - 'nodejs'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, of course it's running every command with `node`, it's explicitly for what that image is done.

When we perform `docker history node:17 --no-trunc`, we can see that the last two layers of the base image are:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["node"]
```

If we get the contents of the `docker-entrypoint.sh` we can see the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Run command with node if the first argument contains a "-" or is not a system command. The last
# part inside the "{}" is a workaround for the following bug in ash/dash:
# https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=874264
if [ "${1#-}" != "${1}" ] || [ -z "$(command -v "${1}")" ] || { [ -f "${1}" ] && ! [ -x "${1}" ]; }; then
  set -- node "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

So since you're using `tsc -w` as first command, it recognizes the dash and the command runs with `node` (as expected).

Also, it seems you misunderstood the functionality of `command` in a Compose file: [**you cannot add more than one command**](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command).

So basically what you're forcing is the following:

```
CMD ["tsc -w", "nodemon"]
```

I suppose what you're trying to achieve is the following:

**package.json**

```
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"nodemon\" "
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
 version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "80:3000"
    container_name: nodejs
    volumes:
      - "./src:/opt/application/src"
    depends_on:
      - "mongo"
    command: npm run start
  mongo:
    image: "mongo:latest"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Comment: I see.. That explains a lot. Yes.. I am trying to concurrent tsc -w and nodemon. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Presumed that you are fully aware that you have set working directory to `/opt/application` in the container. Try:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "80:3000"
    container_name: nodejs
    volumes:
      - "./src:/opt/application/src"
    depends_on:
      - "mongo"
    command: ["tsc","-w","nodemon"]
  mongo:
    image: "mongo:latest"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```